# Open post-content in archive page in a Modal box with bootstrap

Tags: php, posts, javascript, get-posts, id

on my archive page, i m trying to display the post content in a modal box ( using bootstrap).

I manage only to display the first post in a modal box, nothing happen if I click on the other posts from the archive ul li . ..

For this I have assign the post ID to the modal box and the trigger like following:

```
   <div class="post animation-element bounce-up cf" <?php post_class(); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
   <div class="row subject ">


<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-12 ">
<div class="col-md-5">
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal-<? the_ID(); ?>">
<?php the_title();?>
 </a>   
    </div>


<div class="col-md-1"></div>
<div class="col-md-6 subjecttwo vertical">

<div class="row">
<h1 class="title tk-freight-text-pro"><a href="#" title="<?php echo esc_attr( the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
</h1>
  </div>

 </div></div>

 <div class="col-md-1"></div>


</div>

</div>
```

using the following to trigger:

```
  <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal-<? the_ID(); ?>">
<?php the_title();?>
 </a>
```

then the modal box is like there the post content should display is the following:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal-<? the_ID(); ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">    <?php the_title() ?>
</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
<?php the_content() ?>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any idea how it should work ?

If will be super !

Thanks a lot !